# Additive identity in a semiring need not be multiplicative annihilator.

Tags: ring-theory, semiring

We know that an additive identity in a ring is always a multiplicative annihilator. But this doesn't need always be true in case of a semiring. Consider that $e$ is the additive identity of a semiring $S$, then for any $a\in S$, we see that $a.e=a.(e+e)=a.e+a.e \implies a.e=e \iff -a.e \in S.$ Looking for a better suggestion.  Thanks

Comment: you don't have cancellation so you cannot infer $a\cdot e + a \cdot e= a \cdot e \implies a \cdot e =e$

Comment: Yeah i meant $a\cdot e + a\cdot e =a\cdot e \implies a \cdot e=e$ will hold only if inverse exists in $S$ or cancellation law holds in it and as a consequence of this argument, we can conclude that additive identity is not multiplicative annihilator in a general semiring. But $e$ being additive identity is multiplicative annihilator only if semiring is cancellative.

Answer (score 1):

> But this doesn't need always be true in case of a semiring

I’m not sure what definition you’re using, but semirings are usually [*defined*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring) to require that the additive identity is absorbing.

If you’d like an example of something slightly less than a semiring which has a non absorbing zero, see [Examples for almost-semirings without absorbing zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1186702/29335).

Comment: Dear @rschieb, do you mean that additive identity  if exists is multiplicatively absorbing too? Is converse true? i.e, if an element of a semiring is multiplicatively absorbing then will it always be an additive identity?

Comment: @gete In the standard definition of a semiring, additive identity exists and is absorbing.  The converse is probably usually false. For example, you can make any semigroup into a semiring using zero multiplication.