# Multiple definitions of Semirings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, definition, semiring

I am currently studying for my algebra exam and came across the definition of a semiring. Reading through multiple books at once to better understand the definitions and examples I encountered different definitions of semirings.

1. A set $A$ with two binary operations $+$ and $\cdot$ is called a semiring if

   - $(A, +)$ is a commutative semigroup:

     - $(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$ for all $a,b,c \in A$
     - $a + b = b + a$ for all $a,b \in A$
   - $(A, \cdot)$ is a semigroup:

     - $(a \cdot b) \cdot c = a \cdot (b \cdot c)$ for all $a,b,c \in A$
   - Multiplication left and right distributes over addition:

     - $a \cdot (b + c) = (a \cdot b) + (a \cdot c)$ for all $a,b,c \in A$
     - $(a + b) \cdot c = (a \cdot c) + (b \cdot c)$ for all $a,b,c \in A$

This is the "weakest" definition I've found and is from Udo Hebisch, Hanns J. Weinert: Semirings: Algebraic Theory and Application in Computer Science (German - Halbringe. Algebraische Theorie und Anwendungen in der Informatik) ISBN 3-519-02091-2

It does not require an identity element $0$ or an identity element 1 and does not require $0$ to be absorbing.

*What would be an example of that definition?*

2. A set $A$ with two binary operations $+$ and $\cdot$ is called a semiring if

   - $(A, +)$ is a commutative monoid:

     - $(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$ for all $a,b,c \in A$
     - $0 + a = a + 0 = a$ for all $a \in A$
     - $a + b = b + a$ for all $a,b \in A$
   - $(A, \cdot)$ is a semigroup:

     - $(a \cdot b) \cdot c = a \cdot (b \cdot c)$ for all $a,b,c \in A$
   - Multiplication left and right distributes over addition:

     - $a \cdot (b + c) = (a \cdot b) + (a \cdot c)$ for all $a,b,c \in A$
     - $(a + b) \cdot c = (a \cdot c) + (b \cdot c)$ for all $a,b,c \in A$

This is basically the next step by adding an identity element $0$ to the requirements which expands the commutative semigroup $(A, +)$ to a commutative monoid. I've found this definition in my lecture notes from my algebra course.

*What would be an example of that definition?*

3. A set $A$ with two binary operations $+$ and $\cdot$ is called a semiring if

   - $(A, +)$ is a commutative monoid:

     - $(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$ for all $a,b,c \in A$
     - $0 + a = a + 0 = a$ for all $a \in A$
     - $a + b = b + a$ for all $a,b \in A$
   - $(A, \cdot)$ is a monoid:

     - $(a \cdot b) \cdot c = a \cdot (b \cdot c)$ for all $a,b,c \in A$
     - $1 \cdot a = a \cdot 1 = a$ for all $a \in A$
   - Multiplication left and right distributes over addition:

     - $a \cdot (b + c) = (a \cdot b) + (a \cdot c)$ for all $a,b,c \in A$
     - $(a + b) \cdot c = (a \cdot c) + (b \cdot c)$ for all $a,b,c \in A$

This is also a definition I've seen which adds the requirement for an identity element $1$. This leads to $(A, \cdot)$ also being a monoid (not commutative though). I don't even remember if I've seen that definition somewhere or if I made it up but it's most probably from the book mentioned above.

*What would be an example of that definition?*

4. A set $A$ with two binary operations $+$ and $\cdot$ is called a semiring if

   - $(A, +)$ is a commutative monoid:

     - $(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$ for all $a,b,c \in A$
     - $0 + a = a + 0 = a$ for all $a \in A$
     - $a + b = b + a$ for all $a,b \in A$
   - $(A, \cdot)$ is a semigroup:

     - $(a \cdot b) \cdot c = a \cdot (b \cdot c)$ for all $a,b,c \in A$
   - Multiplication left and right distributes over addition:

     - $a \cdot (b + c) = (a \cdot b) + (a \cdot c)$ for all $a,b,c \in A$
     - $(a + b) \cdot c = (a \cdot c) + (b \cdot c)$ for all $a,b,c \in A$
   - Multiplication by 0 annihilates R:

     - 0⋅a = a⋅0 = 0

This definition ditches the identity element 1 again reducing $(A, \cdot)$ back to semigroup again. This is the first time I have seen the requirement for $0$ to be absorbing which makes sense because $0a = 0$ does not hold in semigroups. I've found this definition also in the book mentioned above where it is called a "Hemiring".

*What would be an example of that definition?*

5. A set $A$ with two binary operations $+$ and $\cdot$ is called a semiring if

   - $(A, +)$ is a commutative monoid:

     - $(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$ for all $a,b,c \in A$
     - $0 + a = a + 0 = a$ for all $a \in A$
     - $a + b = b + a$ for all $a,b \in A$
   - $(A, \cdot)$ is a monoid:

     - $(a \cdot b) \cdot c = a \cdot (b \cdot c)$ for all $a,b,c \in A$
     - $1 \cdot a = a \cdot 1 = a$ for all $a \in A$
   - Multiplication left and right distributes over addition:

     - $a \cdot (b + c) = (a \cdot b) + (a \cdot c)$ for all $a,b,c \in A$
     - $(a + b) \cdot c = (a \cdot c) + (b \cdot c)$ for all $a,b,c \in A$
   - Multiplication by 0 annihilates R:

     - 0⋅a = a⋅0 = 0

Basically the same definition as in $3.$ but with the requirement that $0$ is absorbing. This also makes sense as $0a = 0$ also does not hold in general monoids. I've found this definition on the English Wikipedia site which was by far the "strongest" definition in terms of requirements.

*What would be an example of that definition?*

I am not looking for the *true* definition as there is no such thing for semirings but if there are so many definitions with different requirements there have to be examples for each of them.

So, I am basically looking for examples which only fulfill the requirements of the stated definitions and not more because what would be the point in defining a semiring in a specific way then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example for 1):  $(\{n\in\mathbb N|n>0\},+,\cdot)$

Example for 2): $(\mathbb N,+,\cdot)$

In 3), you said the multiplicative monoid isn't necessarily commutative, and yet you wrote the axiom. I'll assume you forgot to remove it. It also seems you explicitly want something with a nonabsorbing $0$.  Example for 3): The best example I know of with nonabsorbing zero is [the one I gave here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1186732/29335), but it is also commutative.  I'm afraid I can't do any better than that at the moment.

Example for 4):  You could just use $(\{n\in\mathbb N|n\neq 1\},+,\cdot)$

Example for 5): $\mathbb N\langle x, y\rangle$, a polynomial semiring with noncommuting variables $x,y$, with coefficients from $\mathbb N$.

The literature for this topic is a bit of a mess.  People use these structures in a lot of different ways. In my experience the most common definition **requires an absorbing identity for $+$** and **an identity for $\cdot$**.

The resources I have used the most on this topic are

> Gondran, M., & Minoux, M. (2008). Graphs, dioids and semirings: new models and algorithms (Vol. 41). Springer Science & Business Media.
>
> Golan, Jonathan S. Semirings and their Applications. Springer Science & Business Media, 2013.

The former is especially detailed about combinations of axioms.

Comment: Whoops my bad! I've messed up a few lines because of copy-paste relics. The semigroups should also not be commutative but associative as in its definition. I edited it. Amazing answer actually so thank you very much! Interesting example for 3). As I wrote, I don't even remember if I've read that definition somewhere or if I've made it up but I'll keep looking for an example!

Comment: The examples in 1), 2) and 4) are all commutative in $(A, \cdot)$ as far as I see, right? Can you also think of examples which are not commutative? For example, if I have a non abelian semigroup on $(A, \cdot)$ with multiplication defined as $x \cdot y = y$ for all $x,y \in A$ I get a problem with the second (right) distributive law.

Comment: @ChristophFritz just do a polynomial ring with no commuting variables and coefficients from the examples I gave.

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot.